# Where's the Pen class in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I want to use the Pen class to teach some basic geometry at my local code club. I can do this with Squeak, but what about Pharo?

```
p := Pen new.
p go: 100.
```

I recall reading that the Pen class has been removed from core Pharo, so is there a way to add it back? Or should I stick to Squeak for this sort of programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gofer it
    squeaksource: 'PharoNonCorePackages';
    package: 'BitBltPen';
    load.
```

Then you can `Display restoreAfter: [Pen example]`

Tested in Pharo 3.0 Update #30826

Answer (score 0):

It was present till Pharo 1.3.

You can file out the BitBltPen package from a [Pharo 1.3 image](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download/release-1-3) and file it in a [Pharo 3 Beta](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download/beta-3-0) image. I just tried it and it seems to work.